# Feature importance with logistic regression with feature names

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I want to find the feature-importance using logistic regression.

My model trained with the code block

```
LR = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', random_state=1, max_iter=1000)
LR.fit(X_train, y_train)
R_y_pred = LR.predict(X_test)
target_names = ['No', 'Yes']
print(classification_report(y_test, R_y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

To find out the feature importance I wrote the code block

```
LR_importance = LR.coef_[0]
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(LR_importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
```

I tried the code block [using this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-feature-importance-with-python/). The result looked like

```
Feature: 1, Score: 0.00545
Feature: 2, Score: 0.00294
Feature: 3, Score: 0.00289
Feature: 4, Score: 0.52992
Feature: 5, Score: 0.42046
Feature: 6, Score: 0.02663
Feature: 7, Score: 0.00304
Feature: 8, Score: 0.00304
Feature: 9, Score: 0.00283
```

However in place of Feature1, Feature 2, Feature3,.... I want the features name of the dataset. How could I do that?

If the dataset contains the features name sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, species, I would like the feature importance result like

```
sepal_length: 0.5
sepal_width: 0.2
petal_length: 0.3
petal_width: 0.1
```

something like that where the features names of the dataset included in the result.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, what happens with `for f, v in zip(LR.feature_names_in_, LR.coef_):
    print(f"Feature: {f}, Score: {v}")`?

Comment: I would like to see the actual name of the features instead of feature1, feature2, feature3,....,